# Compilation errors when creating procedure ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm facing a compilation error while creating a procedure.

This is my procedure.sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE verify IS
  no_of_duplicates NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO no_of_duplicates
    FROM EMPLOYEE
   WHERE E# = (SELECT E# 
                 FROM DRIVER
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT E# 
                                FROM MECHANIC
                               WHERE DRIVER.L# = MECHANIC.L#) );
  IF no_of_duplicates=0 THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('OK');
  ELSE
    SELECT E#, NAME 
      FROM EMPLOYEE
     WHERE E# = (SELECT E# 
                   FROM DRIVER
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT E# 
                                  FROM MECHANIC
                                 WHERE DRIVER.L# = MECHANIC.L#) );
  END IF;
END verify;
/
```

I have been stuck with this for hours and can't seem to find anything wrong with it. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: There is no INTO in your select after IF. Check your queries. And read a book about cursors and exceptions.

Comment: The condition in your IF looks like an assignment?

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: @LukeWoodward That's the thing. I can't seem to find where exactly the error is. All it says when I try to create the procedure is 'Compilation Errors'

Comment: @JoelSeah: in SQL*Plus type `SHOW ERRORS PROCEDURE verify` to find out what the errors are.  If the procedure is the last thing entered, you can just type `SHOW ERRORS`.

Answer (score 1):

When you get compilation errors you can also use the following statement to get a better idea of the error:

```
select * from user_errors where name = 'VERIFY'
```

Also, what @Art said, it looks like it is because you are not using INTO in your second select statement. You will need 2 more variables to hold the E# and name

Comment: Okay. I have created the variables to hold e# and name. So how do i display them?

Comment: In your procedure add dbms_output.put_line(variable) after your if statement then just run the procedure